# Exception when geting distinct values of a field from Mongo collection using mongo Java Driver 3.0

Tags: java, mongodb, mongodb-query, mongodb-java

I'm getting distinct values of field from mongodb. 
When i run the following query in the commandline, it works good.
`db.celldata.distinct("tenentId")`

I'm using Mongo java 3.0 driver,  to retrieve the distinct values using the following query
`MongoCursor<String> iterator = coll.distinct("tenantId", String.class).iterator();`

When i run the query i get the following exception
`org.bson.BsonInvalidOperationException: readString can only be called when CurrentBSONType is STRING, not when CurrentBSONType is NULL.`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well, the root cause of the error here is because you have a `String` type as expected output and one of the distinct values is actually `null`. The way I see it you have two ways of working with this.

Also noting that an "iterator" is overkill for a "distinct" list generally speaking, so just go straight to ArrayList.

Either `.filter()` out the unwanted `null` values:

```
    ArrayList<String> distinct = coll.distinct("tenantId", String.class)
            .filter(new Document("tenantId",new Document("$ne",null)))
            .into(new ArrayList<String>());

    System.out.println(distinct);
```

Or accept the results as BsonValue and handle those:

```
    ArrayList<BsonValue> distinct = coll.distinct("tenantId", BsonValue.class)
            .into(new ArrayList<BsonValue>());

    System.out.println(distinct);
```

But in the latter case, you still need to handle the types returned. There are methods on `BsonValue` to allow you to code for this, but it is also a fair bit of overkill for just getting a list of distinct values.

Therefore as a "third" option, I would go for something with an "un-typed" response. The `.aggregate()` method works will here, but it will be BSON documents in the response, it is still up to you to transfer to a plain ArrayList of different types:

```
    ArrayList<Object> objects = new ArrayList<Object>();

    MongoCursor<Document> iterator = coll.aggregate(Arrays.asList(
            new Document("$group",
                    new Document("_id", "$tenantId")
            )
    )).iterator();

    while (iterator.hasNext()) {
        objects.add(iterator.next().get("_id"));
    }

    System.out.println(objects);
```