# Scala mongodb driver

Tags: mongodb, scala, mongo-scala-driver

Insertion is working fine. Problem is with find()

For find(),

```
val collection: MongoCollection[Machine] =    mongoDB.getCollection(DbConstants.COLLECTION_NAME_MACHINE)

collection.find().subscribe(new Observer[Machine] {

  override def onNext(result: Machine): Unit = println(s"Machine is $result")

  override def onError(e: Throwable): Unit = e.printStackTrace()

  override def onComplete(): Unit = println("Completed")
})
```

It shows Error:

```
org.bson.BsonInvalidOperationException: readString can only be called when CurrentBSONType is STRING, not when CurrentBSONType is OBJECT_ID.
```

In data model for Machine is:

```
case class Machine(_id: String,
    @BsonProperty(DbConstants.FIELD_SITE_ID)siteId: BsonObjectId)
```

folllowing tutorial from: 
http://mongodb.github.io/mongo-scala-driver/2.2/getting-started/quick-tour-case-classes/

Answer (score 0):

You may have null values in the data and that is causing the issue.

[Exception when geting distinct values of a field from Mongo collection using mongo Java Driver 3.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32087849/exception-when-geting-distinct-values-of-a-field-from-mongo-collection-using-mon?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa)